# PHP: Pegar argumento de função com preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Boa tarde:

Estou apanhando para pegar o valor das chamadas a uma determinada função do PHP direto do código fonte.

O que preciso é varrer cada uma das linhas do código-fonte, e existindo uma ou mais chamadas de função altext(), pegar o argumento passado. Por exemplo:

```
<img alt="<?php echo altext('[Este é um texto alternativo]');?>">
```

No caso do exemplo, preciso que me seja retornado apenas "Este é um texto alternativo" (sem aspas). Os [] foram colocados para evitar que, havendo um ') no meio do texto, a busca pare antes do fim.
Estou tentando usar `preg_match_all("/\[altext\]\(\'\[(.*)\]\'\)/", $data, $matches);` mas não está retornando nada. `$data` é a linha de código que busco do código-fonte com `fgets`.

Comment: Você está fazendo um `print_r($matches)` ?

Comment: Sim, o resultado é: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: No código fonte tem essa frase "Este é um texto alternativo" ? E você quer pegar ? Tem certeza que sua regex está certa ?

Comment: Aí é que está o problema: regex não é o meu forte, então tenho estudado o tema, mas não estou conseguindo ver onde está o problema.

Comment: Tente usar essa: `(\W|^)este é um texto alternativo(\W|$)`.

Comment: Neste caso, ele só vai encontrar o que tiver "este é um texto alternativo". Porém, eu tenho várias chamadas à função altext(), porém cada uma delas com um argumento diferente. o que me interessa é o argumento da função, seja ele qual for.

Comment: Só passar a variável dentro da regex. Não é ?
`(\\W|^)$var(\\W|$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui a partir da leitura de um texto do [Martin Streicher](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/os-php-regex1/) e do  [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.meta.php)

```
preg_match_all("/altext\(\'(.*)\'\)/", $data, $matches);
```

E ainda não requer nenhum outro artifício caso apareça um ') no meio do argumento.

Não acredito que era tão fácil. Procurei por dias.

Comment: não é necessário escapar as aspas simples, pode utilizar apenas: `/altext\('(.*)'\)/`. Leitura recomendada: http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/

Answer (score 0):

Coloquei como resposta Everton.

```
$re = "/(\\W|^)este é um texto alternativo(\\W|$)/"; 
preg_match_all($re, $data, $matches);

print_r($matches)
```